# Issue on navigation controller while changing the orientation

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, orientation

I have two view controllers, in which I am using navigation controller to navigate from one view to another.....
In my first view controller I'm checking the orientation in this way in my `- (void)viewDidLoad`

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
{
//Do this task
}
else
{
//Do this task
}
```

When I was trying to navigate from second to first viewcontroller..
I am using this code to navigate

```
-(IBAction)back
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Here the problem arises...
 The above orientation condition is not checked.. When I was trying to navigate from second to first view controller......
I don't know where I was lagging.... Whether I was stuck up with any logics or I want to change my code???????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call this method

```
    -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{


        [self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation duration:0]; 
    }


-(void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown )
    {

    set frame here........  
    }
    else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight )
    {
    set frame here........          

    }



}
```

Comment: What is the need for this method here?Where I want to call this

Comment: Ya I knw this method is called only wen device orientation is changing

Comment: when you called popViewControllerAnimated method viewdidLoad method not called at that time viewWillAppear method called so at that time you called the Rotaion method.